# Get a word from a string array php

Tags: php

How to get a or change a string from an option like the following example

```
{Hay | Hello | Greetings} How are you this {noon | night}
```

with the following results:

```
Hay  How are you this night
Hello How are you this night
Hello How are you this noon
```

and next...

Comment: According to what condition you have to choose the option? Furthermore you have a bad syntax for array. Tell what you want to do more clearly.

Comment: take one {Hay | Hello | Greetings} and then take one more from {noon | night}

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest to use `arrays`
You can make an array and choose an index based on what you need, for example

```
$var1 = array("hay ","hello ","greetings ");
$var2 = array(" noon"," night");
echo $var1[0] . "how are you this" . $var2[1];
```

Would return

```
hay how are you this night
```

NOTE: Take a look at the spaces on the strings in the arrays, if you want to add more text you gotta concatenate with a dot `(.)`

Comment: https://waseru.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/0004-camp20210114152052-300x300.png

the results we wanted

Comment: @KhoirulHamdani So this should work correctly according to the image, or i could say you may have to send the "nama" variable with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first and second word lists in your text can simply be expressed as arrays:

```
$firstWord  = ["Hey", "Hello", "Greetings"];
$secondWord = ["night", "noon"];
```

You can use a string with placeholders and PHPs `printf` statement to bind to those placeholders:

```
$string = "%s. How are you this %s";

printf($string, $firstWord[array_rand($firstWord)], $secondWord[array_rand($secondWord)]);
```

Note:

`array_rand` selects a random key from the array which.